# RODBC Error: Could not SQLExecDirect

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have 2 servers where normally I can query from one to the other successfully by simply adding the server name in the address. I am using Management Studio.  For example:

```
library("RODBC", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
    ch <- odbcConnect("Server1")
    testA <- sqlQuery(ch,paste("SELECT * FROM SampleTableA"))
```

The above works successfully.

However, when I want to query against the second server from the first server, I receive the following error, even after specifying the server name in the address.

```
  testB <- sqlQuery(ch,paste("SELECT * FROM [Server2].[dbo].[SampleTableB]"))

"[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect..."
```

When I perform this same query from management studio it completes successfully, but not from R using the RODBC package.

Obviously, the server and table names are aliases.

Any suggestions?

Also, I tried directly connecting to the second server and that didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, your question seems like it did not get enough attention on Stack Overflow. You can discuss about it in a [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public), if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add two periods between

testB <- sqlQuery(ch,paste("SELECT * FROM [Server2]**..**[SampleTableB]"))